# I cannot display a changing value on the screen in my flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, setstate, riverpod, state-management

I uploaded 3 pages of related code here. My problem is this: I press the `Pick Country` button and select a country, but I can't display my screen the `phoneCode` parameter of the country I selected.

I'm working with flutter_riverpod package and my class type is ConsumerWidget.
So,I can't use the setState() command for this class.

I added a debugPrint to my `void pickCountry()` function. In this way, when I press the Pick Country button, I can see that the relevant value changes in the Debug Console section.
My problem is that this value does not change on the screen.

[Here is my problem on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqdEY.png)

## all_providers.dart

```
final phoneControllerProvider =
    StateProvider<TextEditingController>((ref) => TextEditingController());

final countryProvider = StateProvider<Country?>((ref) => null);
```

## country_code_and_text_field.dart //My Text Widget is here.

```
class CountryCodeAndTextField extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CountryCodeAndTextField({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final phoneController = ref.watch(phoneControllerProvider.notifier);
    final Country? country = ref.watch(countryProvider.notifier).state;

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        if (country != null)
          Text(
              '+${country.phoneCode}', // The part that needs to be updated according to the country I have selected.
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )
        else
          const Text(
            '00',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        SizedBox(
          width: ScreenSize.getWidth(context) * 0.6,
          child: TextField(
            controller: phoneController.state,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter your phone number',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

## login_page.dart // My Pick Country button is here.

```
class LoginPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    Country? currentCountry = ref.read(countryProvider.notifier).state;

    void pickCountry() {
      showCountryPicker(
        context: context,
        onSelect: (Country selectedCountry) {
          currentCountry = selectedCountry;
        },
      );
      debugPrint('selected phone code: ${currentCountry?.phoneCode}');
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          'Enter your phone number',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text(
            'Chattor will need to verify your phone number',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: pickCountry,
            child: const Text(
              'Pick Country',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
            ),
          ),
          const CountryCodeAndTextField(),
          SizedBox(height: ScreenSize.getHeight(context) * 0.63),
          SizedBox(
            width: ScreenSize.getWidth(context) * 0.30,
            height: ScreenSize.getHeight(context) * 0.07,
            child: const NextButtonWidget(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Could you check the line "currentCountry = selectedCountry;" - you need to change the ref.read(countryProvider.notifier).state, not your local variable currentCountry.  2) Could you check if in this line "Country? currentCountry = ref.read(countryProvider.notifier).state;" the method "watch" is needed, not "read"? (Both refers to your login_page.dart file)

Comment: `Country? currentCountry = ref.watch(countryProvider.notifier).state;
    
void pickCountry() {
      showCountryPicker(
        context: context,
        onSelect: (Country selectedCountry) {
          ref.read(countryProvider.notifier).state = selectedCountry;
        },
      );
      debugPrint('selected phone code: ${ref.watch(countryProvider.notifier).state?.phoneCode}');
    }`
I made the corrections you mentioned.
Yes, I can change the state of my provider with selectedCountry, but there is still no change on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think I need to use StateNotifierProvider instead of StateProvider to trigger the build method and change the screen in the flutter_riverpod package.**

```
class CountryNotifier extends StateNotifier<Country?> {
  CountryNotifier() : super(null);

  void setCountry(Country newCountry) {
    state = newCountry;
  }
}

final countryProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CountryNotifier, Country?>((ref) {
  return CountryNotifier();
});

void pickCountry() {
      showCountryPicker(
        context: context,
        onSelect: (Country selectedCountry) {
          ref.read(countryProvider.notifier).setCountry(selectedCountry);
        },
      );
    }
```

**After making these adjustments, my problem was solved.**

Answer (score 0):

The challenge for me to help you, is that you do not provide a code that I can run and then see the problem -- and try to fix it. So I tried to reproduce what you are doing in the following code (that you can copy and paste - and run, so you can see what it achieves and what it does not achieve).
You can see how with the help of Riverpod "picking a country" in a drop down menu actually does change the number presented in the next line. Is this what was missing?
If this solves your problem - great! :-)
If this does NOT solve your problem, then it might nonetheless help us ;-) : It could be helpful for you to describe the challenge that you face more, so that I or others here could better understand it: Could you try to use my code, implement your approach in the most condensed form possible, and let us know what's not working -- and share that with us, so we can look at it and try to find out more?

Here is my take:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class Country {
  const Country({required this.name, required this.numbers});

  final String name;
  final double numbers;
}

const _countryCodes = [
  Country(name: 'Pick Country', numbers: 0),
  Country(name: 'US', numbers: 1),
  Country(name: 'Mexico', numbers: 52),
  Country(name: 'Brazil', numbers: 55),
];

final countryStateProvider = StateProvider<Country>((ref) => _countryCodes[0]);

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 500,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Text('Enter your phone number'),
              const Text('Chatter will need to verify your phone number.'),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              DropdownButton<Country>(
                value: ref.watch(countryStateProvider),
                onChanged: (value) =>
                    ref.read(countryStateProvider.notifier).state = value!,
                items: _countryCodes
                    .map((country) => DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: country,
                          child: Text('${country.name}, +${country.numbers}'),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text('+${ref.watch(countryStateProvider).numbers}'),
                  const SizedBox(width: 20),
                  if (ref.watch(countryStateProvider).numbers == 0)
                    const Text('no country selected'),
                  if (ref.watch(countryStateProvider).numbers != 0)
                    Text(ref.watch(countryStateProvider).name)
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(),
      );
}
```

Comment: The code you gave fulfills the function I want. But I was using a package called country_picker because I didn't want to add all countries manually. 
Anyway, I realized something while working with the code you provided. I think I need to use StateNotifierProvider instead of StateProvider to trigger the build method and change the screen in the flutter_riverpod package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest and help.